# What is the meaning and origin of the surname Lambert?

Tags: surnames

1. What is the meaning of this name?
2. What was the history behind it?
3. Which country does it originated firstly?
4. What ethnicity people will have this name?

Comment: Downvoting is any user's right if they feel your question is not useful, is unclear or does not show any research effort. This particular question can be answered with a simple Google search; perhaps you should try that if you need the answer. Or review the responses to http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1789/104 to understand how you can improve this question.

Comment: http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1755/104 asks if questions like this are on-topic.

Comment: Note also that this user has ["prior form"](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1789/70) and has chosen to ignore the advice that was offered then. Hence my vote to close.

Answer (score 5):

I would say this is being downvoted because of your lack of own research. For example I got with the second search result on google for the search words "Lambert lastname":

> Definition: Bright land or light of the land, the Lambert surname
>   derives from the Germanic elements "land" meaning land and "beraht"
>   meaning bright.
>
> Surname Origin: English, French
>
> Alternate Surname Spellings: LAMBERTH, LAMBETH, LAMBUTH, LAMBER,
>   LAMBERTE, LAMBURT, LAMBRETH, LUMBERT

from [Lambert - Name Meaning & Origin](http://genealogy.about.com/library/surnames/l/bl_name-LAMBERT.htm)

For "Lambert surname" I got:

> The roots of the Lambert family are found in the ancient German state of Bavaria. [...] Lambert derives from the Old Germanic name Landbehrt, which means shining land or holy land.[...]

[Lambert Family Crest and Name History](http://www.houseofnames.com/lambert-family-crest/German)

For "Lambert family name" I got:

> Recorded in over forty spelling forms from Lambert, Lambard and Limprecht, to Lambrich, Lambertini and Lemmens, this surname is almost certainly of very early German origins. As a surname it started life in the 12th century, but the derivation is from a pre 5th century personal name. This was 'Landbehrt', composed of the elements "land", meaning territory, and "berht", bright[...]

from [Last name: Lambert](https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Lambert)

So, from this two minute research alone can be deduced:
1) The words composing the name make up the meaning "bright land" or "shining land", maybe in a meaning of "holy land".
2+3) It is originating from Germany, probably Bavaria or Franconia. There also was a Bishop named "Lambertus" in the 8th century. There is a number of famous people that wore that lastname on wikipedia.
4) Families with the lastname Lambert probably originate from Central Europe, i.e. Germany, Holland, France or UK.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon Lambert is an ancient name from Cappadocia, Syria or there abouts and refers to Lamb(the sheep) and ert from Erten in Turkish meaning early, ancient, former. I believe Lambert refers to the ancient Jews somehow who revered or worshipped the Lamb.

Answer (score -1):

My surname is Lambord but an ancestor of mine changed his name from Lambert to Lambord but we do not know the reason for this. We have relatives in Lincolshire still called Lambert.